# Ef core could not translate my custom sql server STRING_AGG function

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

String.Join in efcore not support and I want to get list of string with separator like sql function String_Agg
I tried to create custom sql server function but i get this error:

> The parameter 'columnPartArg' for the DbFunction 'QueryHelper.StringAgg(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=]],System.String)' has an invalid type 'IEnumerable'. Ensure the parameter type can be mapped by the current provider.

This is my function and OnModelCreatingAddStringAgg for register it in my dbcontext

```
        public static string StringAgg(IEnumerable<string> columnPartArg, [NotParameterized] string separator)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public static void OnModelCreatingAddStringAgg(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var StringAggFuction = typeof(QueryHelper).GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(QueryHelper.StringAgg), new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(string) });
            var stringTypeMapping = new StringTypeMapping("NVARCHAR(MAX)");
            modelBuilder
                .HasDbFunction(StringAggFuction)
                .HasTranslation(args => new SqlFunctionExpression("STRING_AGG",
                 new[]
                       {
                         new SqlFragmentExpression((args.ToArray()[0] as SqlConstantExpression).Value.ToString()),
                        args.ToArray()[1]
                       }
                , nullable: true, argumentsPropagateNullability: new[] { false, false }, StringAggFuction.ReturnType, stringTypeMapping));
        }
```

and this code run above function

```
_context.PersonnelProjectTimeSheets.GroupBy(c => new { c.Date.Date, c.PersonnelId, c.Personnel.PersonnelCode, c.Personnel.FirstName, c.Personnel.LastName})
                    .Select(c => new PersonnelProjectTimeOutputViewModel
                    {
                        IsConfirmed = c.Min(c => (int)(object)(c.IsConfirmed ?? false)) == 1,
                        PersonnelDisplay = c.Key.PersonnelCode + " - " + c.Key.FirstName + " " + c.Key.LastName,
                        PersonnelId = c.Key.PersonnelId,
                        Date = c.Key.Date,
                        ProjectName = QueryHelper.StringAgg(c.Select(x=>x.Project.Name), ", "),
                        TotalWorkTime = 0,
                        WorkTimeInMinutes = c.Sum(c => c.WorkTimeInMinutes),
                    });
```

And also i change my StringAgg method input to
**string columnPartArg**
and change SqlFunctionExpression of OnModelCreatingAddStringAgg to

```
new[]
 {
  new SqlFragmentExpression((args.ToArray()[0] as 
  SqlConstantExpression).Value.ToString()),
  args.ToArray()[1]
 }
```

and change my query code to
**ProjectName = QueryHelper.StringAgg("Project.Name", ", ")**
now when run my query, sql server could not recognize the **Project**

Comment: It is not possible with EF Core right now. Follow this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22957). Custom aggregate functions it is another case which should be handled differently and needs special LINQ Translator support.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the parameter 'columnPartArg' of dbfunction 'STRING_AGG' is varchar or nvarchar. right?

most database function or procedure has not table value as parameter.

in this case,**use EFCore's 'client evaluation'** is good sulution. linq like below：

```
_context.PersonnelProjectTimeSheets.GroupBy(c => new { c.Date.Date, c.PersonnelId, c.Personnel.PersonnelCode, c.Personnel.FirstName, c.Personnel.LastName})
                .Select(c => new PersonnelProjectTimeOutputViewModel
                {
                    IsConfirmed = c.Min(c => (int)(object)(c.IsConfirmed ?? false)) == 1,
                    PersonnelDisplay = c.Key.PersonnelCode + " - " + c.Key.FirstName + " " + c.Key.LastName,
                    PersonnelId = c.Key.PersonnelId,
                    Date = c.Key.Date,
                    ProjectName = string.Join(", ",c.Select(x=>x.Project.Name)),//Client evaluation
                    TotalWorkTime = 0,
                    WorkTimeInMinutes = c.Sum(c => c.WorkTimeInMinutes),
                });
```